# Derivative of the Heaviside step function

Tags: calculus, probability-theory, probability-distributions, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

The Heaviside step function is defined as
$$H(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if }x<0 \\ 1 & \text{if }x\geq0\end{cases}$$
Set also $K(x)=H(2x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$.

Now it is well known (and can be easily proven) that the derivative of $H$ in the sense of distributions is the Dirac delta $\delta_0\,$:
$$H' = \delta_0 \;.$$
Using standard calculus rules I would then expect
$$K' = 2\,H' = 2\,\delta_0 $$
but this is of course not true since $K=H$.

I'd like to understand why I cannot use standard calculus rules and which rules fail (and which do not) when dealing with distributional derivatives.

Comment: I'd say because of the same reason that $\;\delta\;$ is *not* the derivative of $\;H\;$ in the usual sense of differential calculus...and $\;\delta\;$ is not even a function in the usual, basic sense...;)

Comment: Ok, applying the definition of distributional derivative to $K$ we see that the reason why its derivative is still $\delta_0$ is that $\phi(\frac{0}{2})=\phi(0)$ for any test function $\phi$. This seems a very peculiar property of the point $0$... any insight for a general rule?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the chain rule gives you
$$
K'(x) = \frac{d}{dx} H(2x) = 2 H'(2x) = 2\delta(2x) = 2\cdot\frac12\delta(x) = \delta(x)
$$
since $\delta(ax) = \frac{1}{|a|}\delta(x).$

Comment: Can you show that $\delta(ax)=\frac{1}{|a|}\,\delta(x)$ please?

Comment: Simply apply the definition of composition of distributions: $\delta \circ f = \langle \delta, \phi \circ f^{-1} |\text{ det } df^{-1}| \rangle$

Comment: $$\int \delta(ax) \, g(x) \, dx = \{ y=ax \} = \int \delta(y) \, g(y/a) \, \frac{1}{|a|} dy = \frac{1}{|a|} g(0) = \int \frac{1}{|a|}\delta(x)\,g(x)\,dx.$$